# Why are elimination reactions in organic chemistry known as beta eliminations?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Why are organic elimination reactions known as beta eliminations? Why don't we call them alpha eliminations?

Comment: Take 2-bromobutane as an example. The C2 hydrogen is an alpha carbon while the hydrogens are referred to as beta. C4-H's are gamma. It is a generic terminology that fits all cases regardless of the numbering in the compound. There are alpha and beta eliminations.

Comment: Addition:  ...while the C1 and C3 hydrogens are referred to as beta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an elimination reaction we typically have a leaving group (denoted by "X" in the figure below),  The carbon that the leaving group is attached to is referred to as the "alpha" carbon.  If a hydrogen is removed from the "**beta**" carbon, then we have formed an olefin and the reaction is called a **beta elimination**.

[image: The alpha and beta carbons in an elimination reaction]

[[reference](https://www.nextgurukul.in/wiki/concept/cbse/class-12/chemistry/haloalkanes-and-haloarenes/chemical-reactions-of-alkyl-halides-elimination-reactions/3961831#/)]

Sometimes an alpha hydrogen can be removed.  In this case both the hydrogen and leaving group were attached to the same carbon and a carbene is formed.

[image: alpha elimination]

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add to your answer, As to why base  (K OH +alc) attacks beta hydrogen and not alpha hydrogen